# lsm6ds3tr IMU for XIAO BLE Sense in Nordic Connect SDK

Tags: embedded, firmware, nrf52, zephyr-rtos, nrf-connect

I am very new to Nordic SDK and currently having a really hard time with Zephyr. I want to use the inbuilt IMU i.e., lsm6ds3tr_c. Zephyr does not have a driver for the sensor but so far all I could find is that it should be compatible with lsm6dsl which does have a driver. I would really appreciate any help or resources on how can I achieve my goal. Here is the device tree snipped that refers to the sensor.

```
&i2c0 {
    compatible = "nordic,nrf-twim";
    /* Cannot be used together with spi0. */
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-0 = <&i2c0_default>;
    pinctrl-1 = <&i2c0_sleep>;
    pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";
    clock-frequency = <I2C_BITRATE_FAST>;
    
    lsm6ds3tr_c: lsm6ds3tr-c@6a {
        compatible = "st,lsm6dsl";
        reg = <0x6a>;
        irq-gpios = <&gpio0 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        status = "okay";
    };

};
```